# Snap SVG: Creating a scratch animation

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, snap.svg

I'm new to Snap SVG and I'm trying to make a pointer which scratches and make a trail of that scratch path. These are the few issues that I'm trying to fix:

1. The animation starts from the bottom instead of the top.
2. The pointer moves along the path and reaches the top and return back to where it started. It need not have to return to the origin.
3. Need some suggestions to animate the scratch path, it should appear only after the pointer passed through it.

Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<svg id="svgout" width="550px" height="550px"></svg>
```

**JS**

```
var s = Snap("#svgout");

    var scratchPathSVG = '<path class="cls-1" d="M224.58,215.86c-11.57,11.56-23.13,22.08-33.81,33.64C181,259,159.64,286.3,147.19,287.35c-26.69,1.05,0-32.59,7.12-41L189,202.19c21.35-27.33,43.59-53.62,64.94-79.9,9.79-12.62,23.13-24.18,26.69-41,0-2.1,0-4.21-.89-5.26C268.18,63.42,245.93,88.65,237,96c-49.82,44.15-97,94.62-144.12,144-6.23,6.31-28.47,22.08-31.14,31.54C64.45,260,85.8,239,92,231.63l64.05-82c10.68-13.67,69.39-65.18,61.38-88.31-.89-3.15-4.45-7.36-8-5.26-22.24,10.51-40,34.69-57.83,52.56-15.12,15.77-31.14,30.49-46.26,46.26C93.81,166.45,60,211.65,45.77,211.65c11.57,0,56.94-71.49,70.28-87.26C139.18,96,172.1,67.63,189,34c8.9-17.87,10.68-36.79-11.57-33.64C157,2.45,133,36.09,116.94,50.81c-33.81,31.54-66.72,63.08-98.75,95.67C7.51,157,22.64,174.86,33.31,164.35c36.48-36.79,73-73.59,111.2-108.28,10.68-10.51,23.13-18.92,33.81-30.49-.89-2.1-2.67-3.15-3.56-5.26-5.34,7.36-9.79,13.67-15.12,21-16,21-33.81,41-49.82,61C100,114.94,2.17,213.76,35.09,233.73c13.34,7.36,33.81-17.87,41.81-26.28,19.57-18.92,39.14-39.95,57.83-59.92,17.79-18.92,45.37-36.79,58.72-59.92,9.79-16.82,1.78-7.36-5.34,0-10.68,11.56-19.57,24.18-29.36,36.79-16,20-31.14,39.95-46.26,59.92C91.14,212.71,52.88,247.4,44,285.24c-.89,2.1,0,5.26,1.78,7.36.89,1.05,1.78,1.05,1.78,2.1,2.67,2.1,4.45,2.1,7.12,1.05,24.91-12.62,45.37-43.1,64.94-64.13,28.47-29.44,57.83-58.87,87.18-88.31,8.9-8.41,58.72-48.36,57.83-53.62.89,13.67-21.35,32.59-28.47,42.05-28.47,36.79-56.94,74.64-84.52,112.49-5.34,7.36-38.25,44.15-22.24,54.67,19.57,11.56,85.4-72.54,95.19-83.05.89,0,.89-1.05,0,0Z" />';
    var pathToScratch = s.path("M224.58,215.86c-11.57,11.56-23.13,22.08-33.81,33.64C181,259,159.64,286.3,147.19,287.35c-26.69,1.05,0-32.59,7.12-41L189,202.19c21.35-27.33,43.59-53.62,64.94-79.9,9.79-12.62,23.13-24.18,26.69-41,0-2.1,0-4.21-.89-5.26C268.18,63.42,245.93,88.65,237,96c-49.82,44.15-97,94.62-144.12,144-6.23,6.31-28.47,22.08-31.14,31.54C64.45,260,85.8,239,92,231.63l64.05-82c10.68-13.67,69.39-65.18,61.38-88.31-.89-3.15-4.45-7.36-8-5.26-22.24,10.51-40,34.69-57.83,52.56-15.12,15.77-31.14,30.49-46.26,46.26C93.81,166.45,60,211.65,45.77,211.65c11.57,0,56.94-71.49,70.28-87.26C139.18,96,172.1,67.63,189,34c8.9-17.87,10.68-36.79-11.57-33.64C157,2.45,133,36.09,116.94,50.81c-33.81,31.54-66.72,63.08-98.75,95.67C7.51,157,22.64,174.86,33.31,164.35c36.48-36.79,73-73.59,111.2-108.28,10.68-10.51,23.13-18.92,33.81-30.49-.89-2.1-2.67-3.15-3.56-5.26-5.34,7.36-9.79,13.67-15.12,21-16,21-33.81,41-49.82,61C100,114.94,2.17,213.76,35.09,233.73c13.34,7.36,33.81-17.87,41.81-26.28,19.57-18.92,39.14-39.95,57.83-59.92,17.79-18.92,45.37-36.79,58.72-59.92,9.79-16.82,1.78-7.36-5.34,0-10.68,11.56-19.57,24.18-29.36,36.79-16,20-31.14,39.95-46.26,59.92C91.14,212.71,52.88,247.4,44,285.24c-.89,2.1,0,5.26,1.78,7.36.89,1.05,1.78,1.05,1.78,2.1,2.67,2.1,4.45,2.1,7.12,1.05,24.91-12.62,45.37-43.1,64.94-64.13,28.47-29.44,57.83-58.87,87.18-88.31,8.9-8.41,58.72-48.36,57.83-53.62.89,13.67-21.35,32.59-28.47,42.05-28.47,36.79-56.94,74.64-84.52,112.49-5.34,7.36-38.25,44.15-22.24,54.67,19.57,11.56,85.4-72.54,95.19-83.05.89,0,.89-1.05,0,0Z").attr({ fill: "none", opacity: "0" });
    var pointer = s.path("M26.4,182.43c.63.63,1.46.49,1.52-.31.1-1.56-10.56-23.52-11-25.81s0-4.6,2.15-5.7c2.92-1.53,4.54.06,5.82,2.26s6.34,12.55,8.43,17.22c3.09,6.89,10.38,26.09,12.14,26.09,2.75,0,1.41-4.18,1.41-4.18s-2.45-4.1-2.29-5.54a2.75,2.75,0,0,1,3-2.71c2,.35,5.39,2.8,7,5.48,2.63,4.47,9.56,23-7.72,36.29C29.26,239,18.67,227,14.25,221.79A75.28,75.28,0,0,1,3.42,205.33C.25,199-.13,198.64.11,195.81c.26-3.11,4.25-6,9.69.65.59.73,2.18-.18,1.19-1.58-1.53-2.15-5.34-7.65-1.7-10,4.47-2.93,6.42,2.74,8.63,4.16.51.33,1.53-.36,1.42-.86-.53-2.34-4.41-5.15-2.93-8.59a4.18,4.18,0,0,1,6.2-2C24,178.8,25.09,181.13,26.4,182.43Z").attr({ fill: "#666"});
    pointer.drawAtPath( pathToScratch, 10000, );


    function Drawing( svgString, transformString, timeBetweenDraws ) {
        this.fragment = Snap.parse( svgString );
        this.pathArray = this.fragment.selectAll('path');
        this.group = s.g();
        this.timeBetweenDraws = timeBetweenDraws;
    };

    Drawing.prototype.init = function( svgString, transformString ) {
        this.group.clear();
        this.currentPathIndex = 0;

    };

    Drawing.prototype.endReached = function() {
        if( this.currentPathIndex >= this.pathArray.length ) {
            return true;
        };
    };

    Drawing.prototype.callOnFinished = function() {
    }

    Drawing.prototype.initDraw = function() {
        this.init();
        this.draw();
    };

    Drawing.prototype.quickDraw = function() {
        this.init();
        this.timeBetweenDraws = 0;
        this.draw();
    };

    Drawing.prototype.draw = function() {         // this is the main animation bit
        if( this.endReached() ) {
            if( this.callOnFinished ) {
                this.callOnFinished();
                return
            };
        };
        var myPath = this.pathArray[ this.currentPathIndex ] ;

        this.leng = myPath.getTotalLength();

        this.group.append( myPath );

        myPath.attr({
        fill: 'none',
        "stroke-dasharray": this.leng + " " + this.leng,
        "stroke-dashoffset": this.leng
        });

        this.currentPathIndex++;

        myPath.animate({"stroke-dashoffset": 0}, this.timeBetweenDraws, mina.easeout, this.draw.bind( this ) );

    };

    var myDrawing1 = new Drawing( scratchPathSVG, 't0, 0, s1.8', 800 );

    myDrawing1.initDraw();
```

[Js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunvenugopal11/q4L70gLk/2/)

Any ideas /suggestions will be appreciated :)

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It depends what control you have. I'd suggest drawing the path the other way, and don't have a return on it.

Comment: Your animation is following the outline of the brush, but that is not the path it needs to follow, which would be along the middle of the fill. I've published a tutorial about the needed technique for this: https://browser-unplugged.net/blog/calligraphy.en.html. It's also supposed to appear in the next few days on https://css-tricks.com/